# issue with download pdf with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, pdf

I am trying to download pdf with ajax response html for that I am using below code

```js
var newPDFAction =  function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '{{ route("admin.getCustomerSalesRepTotal") }}',
            success: function(response){
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                var specialElementHandlers = {
                    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                        return true;
                    }
                };

                doc.fromHTML(response, 15, 15, {
                    'width': 170,
                        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                });
                doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
            }
        });
        
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<button onclick="newPDFAction()" >Download Record</button>
```

in my ajax response I have received html div with table

```
<div class="card" style="margin:20px; width:100%">
<div class="card-header">
    <img style="width:80px;" src="logo.png" />
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <h3>Customer Sales Rep Sales Totals</h3>
    <table class="table table-borderless">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Total Sales</th>
                <th scope="col">Order Count</th>
                <th scope="col">Customer Account</th>
                <th scope="col">Customer Suff</th>
                <th scope="col">Sales Rep Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Sales Rep Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Sales Rep First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Sales Rep State</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>                                               
            <tr>
                <th>1000.0000</th>
                <td>2</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="card-footer">
    <span style="align:left">Created on: 25-01-2021</span>
</div>
```

but when I run this code I have received below error `jsPDF Warning: rendering issues? provide a callback to fromHTML!` and it is downloading blank file in pdf there is no content in downloaded html response

can anybody help me in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to move the saving command into the `fromHtml` callback:

```
doc.fromHTML(response, 15, 15, {
  'width': 170,
  'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
}, function() {
  doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```

Check an adatped fiddle [here](https://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/gOwNvrW)